# How to use user's input to run another function in Flask - Python?

Tags: python, html, flask

Hi The idea of my code is to allow the user to submit an ID through using this form

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
   return '''
   <form method="get">
    <textarea name="textbox"></textarea>
     <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
      </form> '''
```

Then the user ID is read by this route and other calculations are done

```
@app.route('/')
def api_id():
   text = request.form.get('textbox')
    ## Do other calculations
```

My issue is that when the user inputs the ID nothing happens, only the URL changes but the calculations are not reflected.. Can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the route that will receive the `POST` request from the form:

```
@app.route('/')
def home():
  return '''
   <form method="POST" action="/get_id">
    <textarea name="textbox"></textarea>
    <button type="submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
  </form> 
   '''
@app.route('/get_id', methods=['POST'])
def get_id():
  id = flask.request.form['textbox']
  #do something
```

Comment: More at: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#the-request-object